# How do i form a regex validation where i can input the digit [0-9] but i should not be able to input values having 0000 value?

Tags: javascript

How do i form a regex validation where i can input the digit [0-9] .i.e. 0 is accepted but i should not be able to input values having 0000 values?

Allowed Digits eg: 0, 102340, 1, 120 (maxLength is 6)
Not-Allowed Digits eg: 00, 000, 00000, 0123 and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify, you wan't to only allow numbers without leading digits except 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match only a 0 or any number doesnt start with a 0 `/^0$|^[1-9][0-9]{0,5}$/g`

Comment: np, glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have stored in some variable the number you want to validate, let's call it `number`. Also it's string:

```
number.replace(/^0+(0|([1-9]\d*))$/, "$1");
```

Parenthesis around non-zero digits works in order to keep non-zero digits in the string. $1 matches first regex between parenthesis.

This will work for any length, supposing you're working with positive integers

Comment: `'000'.replace(/^0+([1-9]+)$/, "$1")` still gives `000`

Comment: Thank You for your help Arthur. I have been able to do it. :)